# Spark Streaming Kafka Integration direct Approach EOFException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, eofexception, spark-streaming-kafka

when i run spark streaming example `org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount`,i caught an `EOFException` follow,how can I resolve it

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$createDirectStream$2.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$createDirectStream$2.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:413)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct stream uses a low level Kafka consumer underneath therefore one needs to provide the list of brokers. Most likely you haven't so you may want to set the `metadata.broker.list` property in the form `bhost1:9092,bhost2:9092,...,bhostN:9092`.

See also [Kafka SimpleConsumer cannot connect to zookeeper : Received -1 when reading from channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519466/kafka-simpleconsumer-cannot-connect-to-zookeeper-received-1-when-reading-from).